# Why does rosed not exist in Noetic Windows 10?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS Noetic desktop full on windows 10.

[I have reached in this chapter of the tutorial but i am stuck because of the reason below:](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRosEd)

But the problem is when I call rosed, I get this error

```
C:\Users\zaina\OneDrive\Dokumenter\ros_ws\noetic_ros_1>rosed
'rosed' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It says that rosed does not exist in the ROS Noetic directory, which it normally should.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394206/why-does-rosed-not-exist-in-noetic-windows-10?/) by [zain0097](https://answers.ros.org/users/92780/zain0097/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-01-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @zain0097

EDIT: Sorry I misread the title first time, revised answer.

The list of ros commands available on ROS on Windows are:

```
roscd
rosbag
rosclean
rosconsole
roscore
roscreate-pkg
rosdiagnotic
rosgraph
roslaunch
rosmake
rosmaster
rosmsg
rosmsg-proto
rosnode
rospack
rosparam
rosservice
rossrv
rosstack
rostest
rostime
rostopic
rosunit
roswtf
```

This can be found: opt\ros\noetic\x64\bin

Btw, for other things that have not been ported like `rosdep` check this link:

https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/blob/master/docs/Porting/PortingStatus.md

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-13**:
`rosdep` != `rosed`.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-13**:
Sorry, yes I misread.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-13**:
Unfortunately `rosed` is not included either. To find the list of available equivalent of ros command tools, check this directory: `opt\ros\noetic\x64\bin`